# Derivative of a smooth function $f$ does not depend on curve $\gamma$.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\mathbb{S}$ be regular surface and $f:\mathbb{S}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be smooth function and $p$ be point in $\mathbb{S}$. Then, the derivative of $f$ at point $p$ is $(df)_{p}: T_{p}S\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is linear function given by $(df)_{p}(v)=(f\circ \gamma)'(0)$ where $\gamma$ is a curve in $\mathbb{S}$ such that $\gamma(0)=p$ , $\gamma'(0)=v$.

Here, how can we show that this definition does not depend on $\gamma$? 
Should I show it with projection map? Can you help me?

Comment: Take another such curve with the conditions, and using the chain rule show that the value is the same. You have to recall what the definition of $\gamma'$ is though.

Answer (score 3):

It *does* depend on $\gamma$. It depends on the values of $\gamma(0)$ and $\gamma'(0)$.

But, as Keen-amateur says in his comment above, any two curves $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ with the same $\gamma_i(0)$ and $\gamma'_i(0)$ will give the same $(f\circ\gamma_i)'(0)$. We can see this because when we apply the chain rule, $\gamma_i(0)$ and $\gamma_i'(0)$ are the only two properties of $\gamma_i$ that affect $(f\circ\gamma_i)'(0)$.

In fact, one definition of $T_p\Bbb S$ is the set of equivalence classes of curves $\gamma:\Bbb R\to \Bbb S$ with $\gamma(0) = p$, where two curves $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ are equivalent iff $\gamma_1'(0) = \gamma_2'(0)$ (this requires some chart machinery in order to make rigorous sense, but I skipped it here). The way your definition of "derivative of $f$ at $p$" is phrased makes it seem like it's made specifically to be a function with these very equivalence classes as its domain. Isn't that nice and coherent?